# Div class inside echo PHP

Tags: php, html

I try to put div class in the echo but it does not work really well. The coding is for to change the login button to the username button after user login. The username button will have the drop-down which is the div class. Other things are work well in this coding except for the div class drop-down. Is there another way to put the div class in the echo? Any thought??

[image]

This is before login

[image]

What I expected after Login

[image]

What I get after Login

Below is my coding:

```
<div class="header-right">
    <?php
        if (isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) {
            echo '<a class="active" ><img src="image/user.png" width="22" height="22"> '.$login_session.' <img src="image/drop.png" width="20" height="20" > </a>';
            echo '<div class="box dropdown">
            <ul>
             <a "">edit</a>
              <a "">delete</a>
              <a id="logout" href="logout.php">Log Out</a>
            </ul>
          </div>';
        } else {
            echo '<a class="active" href="login.php"><img src="image/lock.png" width="20" height="20"> Login</a>' ;
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? What did you expect, and what do you get?

Comment: This question is very unclear. However, your HTML is invalid. You can't put `<a>`-tags directly inside `<ul></ul>`. You need to have `<li></li>`'s.

Comment: code needs to be:`<div class="header-right">
<?php
 if (isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) {
  echo '<a class="active" ><img src="image/user.png" width="22" height="22"> '.$login_session.' <img src="image/drop.png" width="20" height="20" > </a>';
  echo '<div class="box dropdown"><ul><li><a "">edit</a></li><li><a "">delete</a></li><li><a id="logout" href="logout.php">Log Out</a></li></ul></div>';
 } else {
  echo '<a class="active" href="login.php"><img src="image/lock.png" width="20" height="20"> Login</a>' ;
 }
?>
</div>`.Make sure `session_start();`will be there on top of your file.

Comment: @AlivetoDie I recommend https://pastebin.com/ for large code blocks as comments. That or actually write it as an answer

Comment: I already edited the question. I make the div(dropdown) at  the different page to test and design. After design, I try to put the div exactly the same coding(html+css) inside the echo. However the outcome it's not the same as I expected. I don't know what the problem is

Comment: okay it's done. I finally found the problem. However thanks, I just want to know how to put the coding correctly because I still new in PHP. Anyway thank you..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use another way to write down this. Let me know if you have any question. I fixed some attribute missing into your anchors `<a>` and list some `<li>` elements into your `<ul>` element as well.

```
<div class="header-right">
    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) { ?>
        <a class="active" >
            <img src="image/user.png" width="22" height="22">
            <?= $login_session ?>
            <img src="image/drop.png" width="20" height="20" >
        </a>
        <div class="box dropdown">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">edit</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">delete</a></li>
                <li><a id="logout" href="logout.php">Log Out</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <a class="active" href="login.php"><img src="image/lock.png" width="20" height="20"> Login</a>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: `$login_session` isn't going to work outside of php.  This hiccup is why I don't like to bounce in and out of php.

Comment: @mickmackusa good catch. Jonathan, you need `<?= $login_session ?>`

Comment: Thanks guys..my coding look more cleaner now but still the design still not the same as what I expected. I don't know what the problem is. I use the same coding as I make the design at the test page.

Comment: Okay, I found the problem..Thanks..it make my coding more cleaner.

Comment: I have one question. How can I make the user redirect at the same page after login. I actually have post a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52490048/redirect-to-the-same-page-after-user-login-php/52492706#52492706. I tried to make it but still fail. The problem is with the session.php

Answer (score 0):

You may put your code in the way like below and I found out your `<ul>` is missing `<li>`.

```
<div class="header-right">
     <?php if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])): ?>
        <!-- Login User (HTML) -->
     <?php else: ?>
        <!-- Not Login User (HTML) -->
     <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I'll always recommend PHP's [alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) for outputting mostly static HTML but I don't think this solves OP's problem

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) { ?>
        <a class="active" >
            <img src="image/user.png" width="22" height="22">
            <?php $login_session ?>
            <img src="image/drop.png" width="20" height="20" >
        </a>
        <div class="box dropdown">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">edit</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">delete</a></li>
                <li><a id="logout" href="logout.php">Log Out</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <a class="active" href="login.php"><img src="image/lock.png" width="20" height="20"> Login</a>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Few words of explanation can help the OP a long way...